# Boolean Reports True When It Should Be False

Tags: java, android

This is intended to detect when the user has pressed the spacebar after typing the letter A. If the spacebar is pressed, the A should be replaced by a C. Otherwise, it should be left alone.

Additionally, if the user presses space but then presses backspace, the replaced letter (C) should become an A and should no longer be replaced.
Basically a weak autocorrect system.

My issue is that the boolean that reports whether the spacebar has been pressed is randomly reporting true when I am just typing random letters and then going back to false.

Any new eyes on this would be much appreciated! I can't seem to figure out what might be causing this to happen. Thanks in advance.

```
public class SpellingsClient extends Activity implements SpellCheckerSession.SpellCheckerSessionListener
{
TextWatcher tt = null;
private EditText suggestions;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    suggestions = new EditText(this);
    setContentView(suggestions);
   // fetchSuggestionsFor(suggestions.getText().toString());

    tt = new TextWatcherExtended() {
        boolean movedOn;

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s, boolean backSpace, boolean autoCorrect){
//Checks if the backspaced was pressed, sets movedOn to false if true
            suggestions.setSelection(s.length());
            if (backSpace){
                Log.d("test2", "Backspace pressed!" + backSpace);
                boolean movedOn = false;
            }
            Log.d("movedOn", "is " + movedOn);
            movedOn = true;
        } 

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
//Checks if spacebar pressed and user moved on, then replaces the word
//if user pressed backspace, it sets the letters back to what they were
            suggestions.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
         if (spacePressed = true && movedOn) {
             suggestions.setText(suggestions.getText().toString().replace("A", "C"));
         } else if (!movedOn) {
             suggestions.setText(suggestions.getText().toString().replace("C", "A"));
         }
         suggestions.addTextChangedListener(tt);
        }
    };
    suggestions.addTextChangedListener(tt);
}
boolean spacePressed;

public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){
//checks if spacebar was pressed and sets spacePressed to true if so
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.d("test", "Space bar pressed!" + event);
        spacePressed = true;
        return true;
    }
    Log.d("Spacepressed", "it's" + spacePressed);
    spacePressed = false;
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spacePressed = true` is your problem. This is an assignment, not a comparison.

Use `==` instead; or, easier, just use `spacePressed`, since `condition == true` is the same as `condition`, and avoids the potential for a typo.